# Verificar se uma div está visivel

Tags: jquery

Preciso saber qual id da div visível, estou procurando sobre isVisible() porem não está dando certo, o que devo fazer ?

Problema:

> Tenho varias divs que tomam contam da tela toda, porém so deixo visivel a tela que está em questão na tela, porém preciso saber qual id desta dela. As telas restantes ficam com propriedade display: none;

Tenho por padrão as divs da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="upage hidden background_PRINCIPAL" id="ID_ESPECIFICO_DA_DIV">
```

e o que estou fazendo é o seguinte:

```
if($('.upage').is(':visible') == 'home'){
}else{}
```

Comment: `.is(':visible');`?

Comment: não sei se é assim mesmo.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues A sugestão do Sergio está correta, é assim que você determina se uma div está visível. Mas se você quer buscar por uma div visível entre um conjunto de divs, basta usar `$(":visible")` (mas provavelmente você vai querer filtrar mais pra não retornar tudo quanto é elemento visível na página inteira, tipo `$(".upage:visible")`).

Comment: E para pegar o ID da div visivel ?

Comment: Para pegar o Id faça assim: `$("div:visible").attr("id");`

Comment: o que você está considerando como visible?

Comment: @durtto Utilizo o que não está com hidden, a dica dos nossos amigos resolveram meu problema e sanaram minha duvida. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Sim, a resposta do @Sergio é muito boa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O jQuery tem um pseudo seletor para isso. O [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) que pode ser usado em combinação com o `.is()`. Desse modo recebes um *Booleano*.

Podes usar assim:

```
var visivel  = $('#minhaDiv').is(':visible');
if (visivel) alert('Sim!');
else alert('Não :( ...');
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLk6ot27/**

ou dentro do próprio seletor assim:

```
var elementos = $('div:visible');
```

neste caso só vai selecionar elementos que estejam visiveis.

Se quiseres saber o ID de vários podes fazer `$('div:visible').get().map(function(el){ return this.id; });`. Se fôr só um podes fazer o mesmo ou usar jQuery assim: `$('div:visible').attr('id')`

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLk6ot27/2/**